# Why hasClass function return false on Javascript added class

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
// function checks that element "elem" has class name "cname"

function hasClass(elem, cname) {
var classArr = elem.className.split(" ");
    for(c in classArr)
      {
          if(classArr[c] === "test")
              return true;
          else
              return false;
      }
}



// function adds class name "cname" to element "elem"
function addClass(elem, cname) {
   var classArr = elem.className.split(" ");
   classArr.push(cname);
   elem.className = classArr.join(" ");
 }

window.onload = function() {
// inside this function you can write some tests
    var box = document.getElementById('holder');
    addClass(box, 'test');
    addClass(box, 'testtest');
    console.log(box);
    console.log(hasClass(box, 'test'));     
};
</script>

/*<div id="holder">#holder<br>(block for tests)</div>
```

class is added through JS addClass function but
My Question here is why console.log(hasClass(box, 'test')) log false after adding class.*/

Comment: You should not use a for in loop for an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this element to body also. Change your onload method to

```
window.onload = function() {
// inside this function you can write some tests
    var box = document.getElementById('holder');
    document.body.appendChild(box );    
    addClass(box, 'test');
    addClass(box, 'testtest');
    console.log(box);
    console.log(hasClass(box, 'test'));     
};
```

Updated the [hasClassMethod](http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/egpnLd9v/5/) as well

```
function hasClass(elem, cname) {
var classArr = elem.className.split(" ");
  console.log(classArr);
    for(c in classArr)
      {
        console.log(classArr[c]);
          if(classArr[c] === "test")
              return true;


      }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: @KhimanandaOli not able to access your link here, can you create a fiddle?